# Set hidden input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function GetWidth(){
    var TBL_width = document.getElementById('wrap_tbl').offsetWidth;
    return TBL_width;
}
var w = GetWidth();

<input type="hidden" id="tbl" value= w />
```

Is this possible?

I want to store a JavaScript variable in value attribute of a hidden input element. Please guide me how to do this

Comment: I think you would profit from reading some basic information about [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM).

Answer (score 8):

`Jquery` version:

```
$("#tbl").val(w);
```

Pure `JavaScript` version:

```
document.getElementById("tbl").value = w;
```

There is no difference between hidden and "unhidden" inputs in this case.

**Advice:** If your's `GetWidth` function has only one line, and the line isn't too much sophisticated, you can extract it from the method.

```
function setWidth(){
    var TBL_width = document.getElementById('wrap_tbl').offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById("tbl").value = TBL_width;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `#`: `$("#tbl")`

Answer (score 4):

Use javascript to set the `value` property of your hidden element:

```
var w=GetWidth();
document.getElementById('tbl').value = w;
```

or jQuery-style:

```
var w=GetWidth();
$('#tbl').val(w);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will definitely not work ... and you already realized that :-)

Look what you did with the element "wrap_tbl" ... you accessed it by using document.getElementById(). You can do the exact same thing to access hidden elements

```
document.getElementById('tbl').value = w;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the value use javascript.

```
document.getElementById('tbl').value=w;
```

If you use jQuery, just `$('#tbl').val(w);`

Answer (score 0):

As the value asignament to the input has already answered, one question,

Do you need it as a param to be sent on submit?

if not, one suggestion: you can allways use the jquery [data method](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20data&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/&ei=P7wOT-7AOY-dOoSpwIQD&usg=AFQjCNEsJ9btyYrc3NJtvQRwCsAoT2nUjQ&cad=rja)

```
$('body').data('myDesiredName','myDesiredValue');
```

and to retrieve it

```
alert($('body').data('myDeesiredName')); //will alert 'myDesiredValue'
```

this way you can allways store multiple values and variables without the need of hidden elements,

happy coding ;)