# passing a javascript variable into a hidden form in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, hidden

I have a page in Codeigniter in which  i can set the product quantity (sq.m) that the client wants to buy. When the client sets the quantity i have to do some calculations (about the quantity number whis was set before) and i am doing that with Javascript setting some variables. Now i want to show these variables in the same (php) page and it's working, but i don't know what should i do to put these variables in the values of the hidden inputs so that i can send them to the controller. Here is the coding:

```
<input type="text"  name="productQuantity">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="return showHide();" value="Calculate Packs">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function showHide() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv");
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
<?php $pack = explode(' ', $pro->productPackSize); ?>
                ele.style.display = "block";

                var val = document.getElementById('productQuantity').value;
                document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = val;
                var req = Math.round(val/<?php echo $pack[0]; ?>);
                document.getElementById('req').innerHTML = req;
                var total = req * <?php echo $pack[0]; ?>;
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;

            }
        }
        // ]]></script>

<div id="showHideDiv" style="display:none;"> 
    <?php echo form_open('main/add_to_cart_validation/' . $pro->productId); ?>
    To cover <strong id="val"></strong> sq.m,  you will need <strong id="req"></strong> Packs 
    which is <strong id="total"></strong> sq.m in total</a> //the ids' here are working, i can show them in the page

<input type="hidden" id="" value="" name="productPacks"> //how can i get the 'reg' variable here?
<input type="hidden" id="" value="" name="productQuantity"> //the same here as above for 'total' variable
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set hidden input value with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833510/set-hidden-input-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines in the else condition after your math:

```
document.getElementById("productPacks").value    = val;
document.getElementById("productQuantity").value = total;
```

Comment: thanks again for your answers, it's working nw but i have another problem which is when the var 'total' is '10.4' for example, and my hidden is: <input type="hidden" id="total2" value="" name="productQuantity"> it's stored in the hidden input as '104', maybe anyone knows what should i do to solve that out?

Comment: Accept the answer it it worked for you, and for the other query see this link http://jsfiddle.net/3GneR/

Comment: Write `document.getElementById("productQuantity").value = new String(total);` instead of `document.getElementById("productQuantity").value = total;`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Starty by giving your inputs an id and then you can pass the values like this :

```
 document.getElementById('myField').value = total;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.You do it the same way.

```
var MyHiddenValue = document.getElementById('myHiddenField').value;

alert(MyHiddenValue);
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xhgXT/)